# Why is logstash slow (1 minute) to start even when I do nothing (-h for example)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, jruby

I work with windows 10. When I try to run logstash it takes around 1 minute to launch. And I'm only trying to display the help message (`-h`). Do any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?

I tried with WSL (just in case) and I have the same behaviour.

I suspect a problem with entropy since adding:

```
-Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false
-Djruby.compile.mode=OFF
-XX:+TieredCompilation
-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1
-client
```

reduces the startup time to about 30 seconds. Which is better but still very long for doing nothing.

Comment: i see the same issue, did you get an insight about fixing it